# Returning array from function with data from file

Tags: c++

I got a C++ program with which I insert the information in a file. I got a second one ( this one ) program to get the data. My goal is to get all the data and return it as array with type Student. In the GetFromFile method I'm getting the information and I can print it, but how I can return it and use it like this in the main function:

```
int size;
Student *students = getFromFile( "D:\\test.txt", size );
cout << students[0].name;
```

The error I'm getting is

```
[Warning] address of local variable `students' returned
```

This is my code:

```
struct Student 
{
   string name;
   char egn[11];
   short grade;
   double avg_grades;
   int excused, unexcused;    
};

Student* getFromFile(string filename, int &length)
{
 fstream file;

 file.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);

 file >> length;

 Student students[length];

 for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
 {
    file >> students[i].name >> students[i].egn >> students[i].grade >> students[i].avg_grades >> students[i].excused >> students[i].unexcused;
 }

file.close();

return students;
}

int main()
{
int size;
Student *students = getFromFile( "D:\\test.txt", size );

cout << students[0].name;
```

Comment: The warning message is very clear. Could you use vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this:

```
file >> length;
Student students[length];
```

Is non-standard extension. Length of array should be known at compile-time.

Secondly, you're returning pointer to the memory that will be released once array goes out of scope. You should use `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <vector>

// ...

std::vector<Student> getFromFile(string filename)
{
    // ...
    std::vector<Student> students(length);
```

Also you no longer need to pass `length` by reference, since `std::vector` has [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) member function.

Answer (score 0):

In `getFromFile` you are returning a pointer to a vector that only exists in that function. Then, in `main` you have a pointer to some data that is not valid.

You should use `Student *students = new Student[length];` in `getFromFile`, and `delete [] students;` in `main` after using the data. But using a vector for this as others say is a better idea.